# Any standard name for this graph?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, directed-graphs

Is there any standard name for the three-vertices tournament which is not a directed triangle (equivalently, for the non-triangle orientation of $K_3$)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

According to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tournament.html,
it was simply called a transitive triple by Harary, which seems sufficient for referring to it. In hindsight, perhaps it can refer to any subset of 3 vertices in a graph with this orientation, so "transitive triplet graph" or such might be better.

Comment: I guess you can call it the $3$-element (total) order.